# Move subversion to a new server without access to the old SVN server

Tags: svn

I had a network computer that acted as my SVN server. I would then check in and out to that server from my local machine.

That server box has since been removed and is no longer available.

I do still have a copy of the SVN repo folders files that were used.

Now, I would like to install SVN server on my local machine just to get my files up to date and so that I am able to check out and export without the SVN folders, which is not possible without an SVN server to connect to.

Once I have set up SVN server locally, how do I import the old repositories? I have seen ways to do this with a dump in SVN server, but as I indicated, my problem is that there is no server except the new one I am installing locally.

Am I screwed or can this still be done? I really do not want to lose past history.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install a svn server. If you have a dump file just create a local repository and import it.

```
svnadmin create your-new-repo
svnadmin load your-new-repo < /path/to/your/dumpfile
```

If you don't have a dumpfile, only the plain svn directory of your svn repository, just use this a your new repository path. Try if you can checkout from it.

```
svn co file:///path/to/your/svn/directory
```

If this work, you can use ***svn switch*** to point your old checked out code to your new repository path.

If you only have a checked out copy of your svn repository you've lost your complete history. Because svn doesn't store the history of your changes localy.

HTH

Jan

Comment: :Thanks-it lead me in the right direction.I did have the SVN directories from the old repositories. I managed to do a checkout, but I could not switch.I instead used the relocate. This got the settings correct, BUT then whenever I tried to do any commands, I would get a "no such revision 459" error. Obviously there was a conflict between what my local revision was at and the server was t. I could not find a way to resolve this, so all i did was checked the last revision from the repo, then added the new files by merging the repo files with my up to date ones,minus svn files and folders.